# Approximating the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\!\big(\frac{e^{-\theta}\theta^k}{k!}\big)^\beta$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, approximation, poisson-distribution

Let $0<\beta\leq 1$, $\theta\geq0$, and consider the series
$$
S(\theta,\beta)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac{e^{-\theta}\theta^k}{k!}\right)^\beta.
$$
How might we determine the upper and lower indicies $k_\ell$ and $k_u$ such that
$$
\sum_{k=k_\ell}^{k_u}\left(\frac{e^{-\theta}\theta^k}{k!}\right)^\beta=(1-\epsilon)S(\theta,\beta)
$$
for choice of small $\epsilon>0$?

The case for $\beta=1$ is easy since the terms of the series represent Poisson probabilities.  This means that one may use the Poisson quantile function, after specifying $\epsilon$, to write
$$
k_\ell(\theta,1)=F^{-1}_\theta(\epsilon/2)
$$
and
$$
k_u(\theta,1)=F^{-1}_\theta(1-\epsilon/2).
$$
For $\beta<1$ the terms in the series, if interpreted as probabilities after multiplying a normailzation constant, result in a probability distribution that is of larger variance and so I suspect
$$
k_\ell(\theta,\beta)\leq k_\ell(\theta,1)
$$
and
$$
k_u(\theta,\beta)\geq k_u(\theta,1).
$$
For my particular application, the less terms in the series I need to obtain the approximation the better.  Computational cost of adding additional terms will be expensive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I shall derive approximations for $k_{\ell ,u} (\theta ,\beta )$ when $\theta$ is large. Assume that $\beta>0$ is fixed. By the results of [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10463-017-0629-6), we have
$$
S(\theta ,\beta ) \sim \frac{1}{{(2\pi \theta )^{(\beta  - 1)/2} \sqrt \beta  }}
$$
as $\theta \to +\infty$. By [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4583924), we have
$$
(\theta  + t\sqrt \theta  )! \sim \sqrt {2\pi }\, \theta ^{\theta  + t\sqrt \theta   + 1/2} \exp \left( { - \theta  + \frac{{t^2 }}{2}} \right)
$$
as $\theta \to +\infty$ uniformly for bounded values of $t$. Thus,
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{k = \theta  - \tau \sqrt \theta  }^{\theta  + \tau \sqrt \theta  } {\left( {\frac{{{\rm e}^{ - \theta } \theta ^k }}{{k!}}} \right)^\beta  } & \sim \int_{\theta  - \tau \sqrt \theta  }^{\theta  + \tau \sqrt \theta  } {\left( {\frac{{{\rm e}^{ - \theta } \theta ^s }}{{s!}}} \right)^\beta  {\rm d}s}  = \sqrt \theta  \int_{ - \tau }^\tau  {\left( {\frac{{{\rm e}^{ - \theta } \theta ^{\theta  + t\sqrt \theta  } }}{{(\theta  + t\sqrt \theta  )!}}} \right)^\beta  {\rm d}t} \\ & \sim \frac{{\sqrt \theta  }}{{(2\pi \theta )^{\beta /2} }}\int_{ - \tau }^\tau  {\exp \left( { - \frac{{t^2 }}{2}\beta } \right){\rm d}t}  = \frac{1}{{(2\pi \theta )^{(\beta  - 1)/2} \sqrt \beta  }}\operatorname{erf}\left( {\sqrt {\frac{\beta }{2}} \tau } \right) \\ & \sim S(\theta ,\beta )\operatorname{erf}\left( {\sqrt {\frac{\beta }{2}} \tau } \right) = S(\theta ,\beta )\left(1-\operatorname{erfc}\left( {\sqrt {\frac{\beta }{2}} \tau } \right)\right)
\end{align*}
for large positive $\theta$ and bounded $\tau>0$. Here $\operatorname{erf}$ and $\operatorname{erfc}$ denote the [error function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/7.2.E1) and the [complementary error function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/7.2.E2), respectively. Thus, for any fixed $0<\varepsilon<1$, one may take
$$
k_{\ell ,u} (\theta ,\beta ) \approx \theta  \mp \tau _\varepsilon  \sqrt \theta  
$$
where $\tau_\varepsilon$ is the unique positive solution of the equation
$$
\operatorname{erfc}\left( {\sqrt {\frac{\beta }{2}} \tau _\varepsilon  } \right) = \varepsilon .
$$
(See [here](http://dlmf.nist.gov/7.17.iii) for approximate solutions.)