Find constant for asymptotic equivalence (Stirling's formula)
Find constant $A$ such that $C_{n^2}^{n} \sim A\frac{n^{2n}}{n!}$
Writing $C_{n^2}^{n}$ using Stirling's formula gives $C_{n^2}^{n} \sim \frac{n^{2n}}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{n-1}} \sim \frac{n^{2n}}{\sqrt{2 \pi n}}$
I've tried to find some A so it was possible to use Stirling's formula once again but the problem is that this way A turns out to be a function of n, not a constant...
How can we solve it?

If we look at the limit of $C_{2n}^{n} \cdot \frac{n!}{n^{2n}}$ then Wolfram Alpha gives $\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}$. Using Stirling's formula I got that $C_{2n}^{n} \cdot \frac{n!}{n^{2n}} \sim \frac{1}{e^n}$ and it does not match with the answer from Wolfram Alpha

The above comment should be included in the question statement.

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4567136

We have
\begin{align}
\binom{n^2}{n}&=\frac{(n^2)!}{(n^2-n)!n!}
=\frac{(n^2)^{n^2}e^{-n^2}\sqrt{2\pi n^2}}{
(n^2-n)^{n^2-n} e^{-(n^2-n)}\sqrt{2\pi (n^2-n)}\cdot 
n^n e^{-n}\sqrt{2\pi n}
}(1+o(1))
\\ &
=\frac{(n^2)^{n^2}}{(n^2-n)^{n^2-n} \cdot n^n \sqrt{2\pi n}}(1+o(1))
=\frac{n^{2n^2}(1+o(1))}{
(n^2)^{n^2-n}(1-1/n)^{n^2-n} \cdot n^n \sqrt{2\pi n}}
\\ &
=\frac{n^{2n^2}(1+o(1))}{
n^{2n^2-n}\left(1-\frac 1n\right)^{n^2-n} \sqrt{2\pi n}}
=\frac{n^{n}(1+o(1))}{
\left[e^{\log(1-1/n)}\right]^{n(n-1)} \sqrt{2\pi n}}
=\frac{n^{n}(1+o(1))}{
e^{-n+\frac12+o(1)} \sqrt{2\pi n}}
\\ &
=\frac{n^{2n}(1+o(1))}{
n^n e^{-n+\frac12+o(1)} \sqrt{2\pi n}}
=\frac{n^{2n}}{
n! e^{\frac12}}(1+o(1))
\end{align}
which is what you wanted.

you are absolutely right and I made a terrible typo in my question. it is $C_{n^2}^{n}$ and not $C_{2n}{n}$, sorry for misunderstanding

Hint We can just as well look for a constant $A$ that satisfies $n! {n^2 \choose n} \sim A n^{2 n}$, or
$$\frac{(n^2)!}{(n^2 - n)!} \sim A n^{2 n}.$$
Now, Stirling's approximation can be written as
$$\log(u!) = u \log u - u + \frac12 \log u + \frac12 \log(2 \pi) + \cdots.$$
Herein $\cdots$ denotes terms that are $o(1)$.
Substituting gives
\begin{multline}
\log ((n^2 - n)!) \\
= (n^2 - n) \log (n^2 - n) - (n^2 - n) + \frac12 \log (n^2 - n) + \frac12 \log(2 \pi) + \cdots .
\end{multline}
Now (again all asymptotics are taken at $\infty$),
$$\log (n^2 \color{#bf0000}{- n}) = 2 \log n \color{#bf0000}{- \frac1n - \frac{1}{2 n^2}} + \cdots,$$
where the highlighting herein denotes terms resulting from the $-n$ in the argument of $\log(n^2 \color{#bf0000}{- n})$. Substituting, keeping track only of terms of at least constant order, and simplifying gives
\begin{align}\log((&n^2 \color{#bf0000}{- n}) !) \\
&= (n^2 \color{#bf0000}{- n}) \left(2 \log n \color{#bf0000}{- \frac1n - \frac1{2n^2}}\right) - (n^2 \color{#bf0000}{- n}) - \frac12 (2 \log n) \\
&\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad + \frac12 \log (2 \pi) + \cdots \\
&= 2 n^2 \log n - n^2 - \color{#bf0000}{2 n \log n} + \log n + \color{#bf0000}{\frac12} + \log(2 \pi) + \cdots .
\end{align}
Ignoring the highlighted terms gives the series expansion for $\log ((n^2)!)$. So,
$$\log \frac{(n^2)!}{(n^2 \color{#bf0000}{- n})!} = \log ((n^2)!) - \log ((n^2 \color{#bf0000}{- n})!) = \color{#bf0000}{2 n \log n - \frac12} + \cdots,$$
and exponentiating recovers
$$n! {{n^2} \choose n} = \exp\left(\color{#bf0000}{2 n \log n - \frac12} + \cdots\right) \sim \color{#bf0000}{\frac{1}{\sqrt e} n^{2 n}} .$$
Essentially the same computation gives for fixed $\lambda > 0$ that ${n^2 \choose \lambda n} \sim \exp \left(-\frac{\lambda^2}2\right) n^{2 \lambda n} $

Wilse, how did you get this result for $(n^{2}-n)!$? how did you get exponent under the square root, could you write it in a more detailed way, please?

@JohnDoe I wrote up a more detailed computation. I find it easier to work with expansions of logarithms of factorial/binomial quantities, which is what I've done here. The essence of the computation is determining which initial terms in the expansion change when switching between $\log (n^2)$ and $\log (n^2 - n)$.
